# multiple color categorical scatter plot python could not convert string to float

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a set of data into one plot. I loaded the data into a list of tuples, each element is the tuple (time_list, data_list).

I want to plot the scatter plot of all days of data in one figure with different colors, x-axis as the time, y-axis as the data.

However I got the error message saying: could not convert string to float

This is what I did:

```
labels = ['S', 'M']
colors = ['pink','orange']

plt.figure()
plt.title ('Daily Call Volumn By Day')

count = 0
for i in totalcalls:
    xval = i[0]
    yval = i[1]
    plt.scatter(x = xval, y = yval, color = colors[count], label = labels[count])
    count += 1
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

The tuple list looks like this:

```
totalcalls =
[(['2004-05-02 00:00:00',
   '2004-05-09 00:00:00',
   '2004-05-16 00:00:00',
   '2004-05-23 00:00:00',
   '2004-05-30 00:00:00',
   '2004-06-06 00:00:00',
   '2004-06-13 00:00:00',
   '2004-06-20 00:00:00',
   '2004-06-27 00:00:00',
   '2004-07-04 00:00:00',
   '2004-07-11 00:00:00',
   '2004-07-18 00:00:00',
   '2004-07-25 00:00:00',
   '2004-08-01 00:00:00',
   '2004-08-08 00:00:00',
   '2004-08-15 00:00:00',
   '2004-08-29 00:00:00'],
  [464.42424242424244,
   385.63636363636363,
   401.93939393939394,
   363.60606060606062,
   371.30303030303031,
   341.45454545454544,
   392.72727272727275,
   423.4848484848485,
   390.93939393939394,
   396.75757575757575,
   410.75757575757575,
   400.84848484848487,
   376.72727272727275,
   376.15151515151513,
   430.4848484848485,
   464.09090909090907,
   379.36363636363637]),
 (['2004-05-03 00:00:00',
   '2004-05-10 00:00:00',
   '2004-05-17 00:00:00',
   '2004-05-24 00:00:00',
   '2004-05-31 00:00:00',
   '2004-06-07 00:00:00',
   '2004-06-14 00:00:00',
   '2004-06-21 00:00:00',
   '2004-06-28 00:00:00',
   '2004-07-05 00:00:00',
   '2004-07-12 00:00:00',
   '2004-07-19 00:00:00',
   '2004-07-26 00:00:00',
   '2004-08-02 00:00:00',
   '2004-08-09 00:00:00',
   '2004-08-16 00:00:00',
   '2004-08-23 00:00:00',
   '2004-08-30 00:00:00'],
  [441.5151515151515,
   418.84848484848487,
   387.27272727272725,
   351.72727272727275,
   394.72727272727275,
   373.18181818181819,
   384.69696969696969,
   399.90909090909093,
   362.06060606060606,
   372.75757575757575,
   383.57575757575756,
   386.93939393939394,
   387.21212121212119,
   369.4848484848485,
   410.06060606060606,
   428.27272727272725,
   419.87878787878788,
   389.030303030303])
]
```

It seems that the logic is right, but I just cannot fix this.
Thank you!

Comment: No problem running your code here. Are you using latest version of matplotlib?

Comment: As @Aguy said, check `print(matplotlib.__version__)`. The use of categorical data was introduced in 2.1, I think. Older versions don't support this function, definitely not 1.5.

Comment: I don't think you want to plot your dates as categories. Instead convert them to dates, i.e. `datetime` objects.